# Getting different image arrays after doing the same operation in Image Sharpening

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to sharpen an image by applying unsharp masking, where you subtract your image with the Gaussian blurred image and then add the difference back to the image.

Here is the code which I ran:

```
 img = cv2.imread('redhat.jpg')
 gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(7,7),0)
 diff = img - gauss
 sharp = img + diff
 cv2_imshow(img)
 cv2_imshow(sharp)
```

original image:

[image]

sharp:

[image]

Instead of above code, if I run:

```
 img = cv2.imread('redhat.jpg')
 gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(7,7),0)
 sharp = cv2.addWeighted(img, 2, gauss, -1, 0)
 cv2_imshow(img)
 cv2_imshow(sharp)
```

then I am getting the correct sharp image:

[image]

Can someone explain to me why I got weird results in the first code? Per my understanding both the pieces of code are doing the same mathematical operations.

Answer (score 2):

In `diff = img - gauss`, the subtraction produces negative values, but the two inputs are of type uint8, so the result of the operation is coerced to that same type, which cannot hold negative values.

You’d have to convert one of the images to a signed type for this to work. For example:

```py
gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(7,7),0)
diff = img.astype(np.int_) - gauss
sharp = np.clip(img + diff, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Using `cv2.addWeighted()` is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the difference is caused by over/underflow in

`diff = img - gauss`

If the source images have both 8-bit unsigned integer depth, the diff will have the same depth as well, which can cause underflow in the subtraction operation.

In contrast, `addWeighted()`, performs the operation in double precision, and perform saturation cast to the destination type after the operation (see [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19)). That effectively reduces the likelihood of over/underflow, and cast will automatically trim the values to the supported range of the destination scalar type.

If you still want to use the first approach, either convert the images to floating point depth, or use big enough signed integers. After the operation, you may need to perform saturation cast to the destination depth.